# Odoo 9 : Delegation inheritance and inherited view

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-view

I have a model which inherits by delegation:

```
class MyResPartner(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.res.partner'
    _inherits = {'res.partner': 'partner_id'}
    partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', required=True, autojoin=True, ondelete='cascade')
    diffuser_summary = fields.Text('Récapitulatif Diffuseurs')
    diffuser_details = fields.Text('Détails Diffuseurs')
```

Now, i want to inherit from res.partner.form to display my fields in a new tab :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
    <record id="res_partner_view_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Ma fiche partenaire</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="state_id" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
            </field>
            <field name="category_id" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="string">Type</attribute>
            </field>
            <page name="internal_notes" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
            </page>
            <page name="sales_purchases" position="before">
                <page name="page_technical_information" string="Infos Techniques">
                    <group name="group_technical_information">
                        <field name="diffuser_summary" />
                        <field name="diffuser_details" />
                    </group>
                </page>
            </page>
        </field>
    </record>
</openerp>
```

It doesn't work because Odoo doesn't find my extended fields 'diffuser_summary' and 'diffuser_details' in the view. It's normal because i use the model 'res.partner', but when i change to 'my.res.partner', the view skip my inherited view and display the standard view.

It works when i use classic inheritance.

I haven't found how to inherit a view with a model with delegation inheritance.

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't work with <field name="model">my.res.partner</field> ? I think that's the same way for product.template and product.product. Maybe take a look at these two.

Comment: I tried with <field name="model">my.res.partner</field>, but in this case, the view isn't displayed : only the original view is displayed, but not mine. I make a mistake, but i can't find where...

Comment: How do you use your model: as many2one anywhere (with popup form) or with a menu and an action?

Comment: I just would like to use my model in replacement of the classic partner model, with my additional fields. I'm new in Odoo (working with the book "Odoo Development Essentials" : the author explains how to inherit model by delegation, but doesn't explain how to interface it with a view). I think there is something i didn't understand...

Comment: Why do you want to replace the classic partner model? Why don't you just extend it?

Comment: I think my explanations are not clear. I just wanted to add some extra fields, but in the book "Odoo Development Essentials", the author explains that it can be better to inherit by delegation instead of classic inheritance (better for database). So, i tried to inherited by delegation from "res.partner" model and it works, but after, i can't inherited the view and integrate my new fields. Nothing happens. It works with model and classic inheritance but not by delegation. Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: The problem here: you can't use the business logic and you have to create your own views, menus and actions to "show" your new model (and it is a new business model, which uses another inside). Some examples: product.product (product.template) and res.users (res.partner).

Comment: Yes, I thought so'. So it's simpler to do classic inheritance instead of composition. It just runs along on its own.